# Need to redirect warnings in python check_output

Tags: python, subprocess, openstack

I get warnings while using check_output function and I am unable to redirect the warnings. I suppose stderr will only take errors and subprocess.check_output cannot deal with warnings (not sure though). Can anyone suggest?

```
def getSnapshot(volumeName):
    try:

        snapID, snapAttach = check_output(["openstack", "volume", "snapshot", "list", "--volume", volumeName, "-c", "Name", "-c", "ID", "-f", "value"]).rstrip().split()
        myDict['snapshot'] = [snapAttach, snapID]
    except ValueError:
        myDict['snapshot'] = None
    return myDict
```

Type of warnings:

```
WARNING: openstackclient.common.utils is deprecated and will be removed after Jun 2017. Please use osc_lib.utils. This warning is caused by an out-of-date import in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/heatclient/osc/plugin.py\nIgnoring domain related config project_domain_id because identity API version is 2.0\n
```

Comment: Why dont you fix the problem with openstack instead of working around it in your python script ? :D

Comment: Its running on the other servers which I dont have access to.

Comment: Warnings should be either in `stdin` or `stderr`. There is no such think as `stdwarn`. Where do yo see the warning?

Comment: The warning is from the openstack environment. The command under check_output is responsible for warnings

Answer (score 0):

May be suitable for what you are wanting. https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html

```
    import warnings

    def fxn():
        warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
        fxn()
```